# How should I adjust my half-marathon training schedule after missing a week?

Tags: running, half-marathon

I'm running my first half marathon on 10/23. I had been training with a schedule that added a mile to the long run every week. The last three weeks of the schedule look like this:

```
| Week |  M   |   T   |   W   |   Th  |   F   |   Sa  |   Su   |
|------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------|
|   8  |  0   |   4   |   4   |   5   |   0   |   2   |   12   |
|   9  |  0   |   3   |   3   |   5   |   0   |   2   |   5    |
|  10  |  0   |   3   |   3   |   4   |   0   |   2   |   13.1 |
```

Due to travel, I didn't run at all during week 8. Now I'm trying to decide how to adjust weeks 9 and 10. Should I just leave it as is? I'm mostly interested in keeping my joints happy and healthy. Maintaining/Improving upon my ~11 minute mile pace for long runs is secondary to that.

Comment: Do the week as-is. As the 13.1 miles is on the week after I would not suggest bringing the 12 miles run week forwards.

Comment: can you stay in aerobic zone with 11 min/mile pace for the whole run?

Comment: @Anatoly I did with my 11 mile run (although maybe slightly slower at first and slightly faster towards the end), and I have with my 5-mile runs after my skipped week. We'll see about the actual half marathon though.

Comment: @BenLindsay how was the 1/2 marathon?

Comment: @Anatoly Ha, could have been better. I actually wasn't feeling well that morning and didn't eat enough before the race so the first couple miles felt awful until I got some gatorade in me. The good news was that because it was a cheap race, they messed up and only had us run 12.6 miles :) I ran 12.6 miles in 2:22:23.1 which by my calculation is 11:18 a mile which I only now just realized doesn't match the 11:40 pace they told me I had...I guess you get what you pay for ;)

Comment: @Anatoly Correction: actually it was 12.5 miles for an 11 min 23.5 second mile pace.

Comment: anyway 2:22 is good time, great job! I target the same for my first 1/2 marathon Saturday this week. Make sure you signup for next one :)

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks! I'll probably do another one eventually. good luck on yours!

Comment: I finished with time 2:12, my friend told me next time it has to be 2:00, so have to signup to next one too. I continue train following  Arthur Lydiard method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the week as-is. As the 13.1 miles is on the week after I would not suggest bringing the 12 miles run week forwards.